# SideBar decleration

Tags: ios, swift, sidebar

I'm not using the storyboard mode to make a table along with creating a button to call it. I have the code to make it swipe but for some reason I cant make the button call the sidebar. I have a `sideBartableViewController` that creates the `tableview` and the **SideBar.swift** file to give it the functionality. I think I have to give the **sidebar.swift** file an extra function to open up the `sideBar` when the button is pressed. All I have is the swipe motion embedded into the **SideBar.swift** file. Any help would be appreciated!If you need the code for the `sideBarTableViewController` or `SideBar` I can post it up

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Menu Button
    let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 17, 45, 43)
    //button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    //button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    var buttonMenu = UIImage(named: "menu-button.png")
    var buttonMenuView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 17, 45, 43))
    buttonMenuView.image = buttonMenu
    self.view.addSubview(buttonMenuView)

    // Side bar action and text
    sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Business Directory", "Classifieds", "Featured News", "Jobs", "Restaurants", "Sports"])
    sideBar.delegate = self


}

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    if sideBar = SideBar.self{
        sideBarWillOpen()

    }else{ sideBarWillClose()
    }



    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the sideBar added to the view?  Something like: `self.view.addSubview(sidebar.view)`

Comment: If I dont have it where should I put self.view.addSubview(sidebar.view)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I incorrectly assumed your sideBar was the UIViewController.  After seeing your SideBar Class, I see it's an NSObject that handles showing/hiding the table view controller.  So all you have to do is check if the sideBar is open or not and show/hide it accordingly.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if sideBar.isSideBarOpen {
        sideBar.showSideBar(false)
    } else {
        sideBar.showSideBar(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was an easy call I just didnt know how to do it. Man I worked on this in all sorts of ways and it was just a simple code. 5 stars for you my good sir

Comment: Just a quick thought how would you tell the sidebar to close when you click out of it?

Comment: You could add a tap gesture recognizer to the originView that closes the side bar if it is open.

Comment: Should I write the tap gesture as a function or along with the if else statement in the buttonAction function?

Comment: You should add the tap gesture in the SideBar class init right under where the other gestures are

Comment: I'm getting an error        let tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "Tapped")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

Comment: func Tapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 1{
            showSideBar(false)
            delegate?.sideBarWillClose!()
        }

Comment: This is getting off topic of the original question. You should ask a new question.  That being said, the action needs a colon which designates that it has a parameter "Tapped:"

Comment: I figured it out! I was just missing the Tapped: and a ? mark at the end of sideBarwillClose?() thanks for all the help

Comment: Yea I know I was thinking the same thing as asking a different question on the forum! But really thanks a lot you helped tons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the sideBar.view to the view hierarchy.

Here's a general way to do a custom menu/sidebar.

```
func showSideBar() {
    // if sideBar is nil, then init it and set delegate
    if sideBar == nil {
        // init the sideBar
        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Business Directory", "Classifieds", "Featured News", "Jobs", "Restaurants", "Sports"])
        sideBar.delegate = self
    }
    // add it off the right side of the screen
    sideBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height) // customize the width and height here
    self.view.addSubview(sideBar.view)
    // animate onto the screen
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {()
        self.sideBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)
    })
}

func hideSideBar() {
    if sideBar != nil {
        // animate off the right side of the screen
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {()
                self.sideBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to coding so forgive me for not knowing much. I'm coming up with errors when I add your code. Where exactly should I put this code? In my ViewController, SideBar, or SideBarTableViewController?

Comment: put this in your ViewController

Comment: Okay! So I put it in my ViewController and its has a couple of errors saying if sideBar == nil  -> Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type (@Lvalue SideBar, NiLiteralConvertible)                     and sideBar.view.frame -> SideBar doesn not have a member named 'view'

Comment: Please post your SideBar class.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you're doing.  Your sideBar is an NSObject that controls showing/hiding SideBarTableViewController.  The answer will be quite different than what I posted in this answer, so I'll add a new answer.